# useRef type on React Draggable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, draggable, use-ref

I am relatively new to coding and especially to Typescript. I am trying to create a React Draggable modal that changes its bounds when the window gets resized and move the modal with it, so it never gets out of the window. I have created a function that does that but I am struggling to use the correct type for the ref `draggableRef` that is used on the actual draggable. What type is the `draggableRef`? Whatever I change it to there is problem with the `.state.x;` on the `modalOffsetLeft` that it doesn't exist on it.
Or, is there other way to do it? Thanks!

here is the code:

```
    export const DraggableModal: React.FC<DraggableModalProps> = ({
    draggableProps,
    onClose,
}) => {
    const [bounds, setBounds] = useState({
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
    });
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const draggableRef = useRef<DraggableCore>(null);
    const rootWindow = document.getElementById('root') as HTMLDivElement;


const getValues = () => {
        if (ref.current !== null && draggableRef.current !== null) {
            const modalWidth = ref?.current?.clientWidth;
            const draggableWindowWidth = rootWindow?.clientWidth - modalWidth;
            const modalOffsetLeft = draggableRef?.current?.state.x;

            setBounds({
                width: draggableWindowWidth,
                height: rootWindow?.clientHeight - ref.current.offsetHeight,
            });

            if (modalOffsetLeft > draggableWindowWidth) {
                draggableRef.current.state.x = draggableWindowWidth;
            }
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getValues();
    }, []);

    parent.onresize = getValues;

    return (
        <Draggable
            ref={draggableRef}
            bounds={{
                left: 0,
                top: 0,
                right: bounds.width,
                bottom: bounds.height,
            }}
            {...draggableProps}
            handle="#handle"
        >
            <DraggableWrapper>
          ...
        </DraggableWrapper>
     ....
```

Comment: if you hover over `ref=`, it should tell you what type the ref is. Only `Draggable` knows what `ref` returns.

Comment: What is there inside `Draggable`? Does it forward the ref to a `div`?

Answer (score 0):

instead of updating its x,y using ref try to create a state {x,y} and then update this x and y.
then pass x and y to position props in Draggable.

by the way you can run the function get values in the more clearing way by adding the function to a listner that runs when the window is changes.

Comment: But doesn't it then become "controlled" meaning that the user then actually can't drag it? As it's written in the documentation: 

// Much like React form elements, if this property is present, the item
// becomes 'controlled' and is not responsive to user input. Use `position`
// if you need to have direct control of the element.

Cause that sort of looses the meaning of it.

Comment: yes it may be true. I don't know about this package.